# Running thousands of MySQL queries via putty

Tags: mysql, putty

Every time I try to run more than a few insert into queries on my ubunutu mysql database via putty I get errors from one or more rows that fail to update, and if it's hundreds or more, it usually crashes or is pauses from an incomplete query presumably. This has nothing to do with the syntax of the queries as when I run them individually they run fine. I there anything I can do to run fix this?

Comment: What do you mean "via PuTTY"; how exactly are you running these queries?  Are you SSHing in and manually entering them on the `mysql` prompt?  Are you trying to run them from a `.sql` file?

Comment: You should probably wrap the INSERT queries in a transaction.  Run `START TRANSACTION;` (or `BEGIN;`) before the queries and `COMMIT;` afterwards.  See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html

Comment: Is PuTTY connected the whole time?

Comment: The provided description of the observed behavior "get errors from one or more rows" is not useful for determining the cause of the errors. Yes, there is probably a fix. But it really *depends* on diagnosing the actual problem. (What are the actual error messages that are returned?) My suspicion (and this is just a guess) is a "right click paste" of a large amount of text into a PuTTY window is involved. As Rocket Hazmat mentions, I suggest you put the statements into a text file, transfer the file to the host where you're running the mysql command, and use `source` to execute from the file

Comment: Your problem description isn't detailed enough for us to help you. Please [edit] your question to show an example of the SQL command you issue and the error you get.

Comment: I'm copying and pasting queries from an excel spreadsheet onto the mysql command line in putty. Putty is connected the whole time. It's tricky to debug as putty puts a limit to the number of lines it displays.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Rocket's solution but it did much the same thing (skipping rows and then hangs).

I've just noticed there are carriage returns and line feeds in the data so after removing those it seems to be working wihtout any errors but is taking absolutely ages using the BEGIN, COMMIT method. Maybe because it is only parsing one single really long line now instead of several lines at a time.

Comment: The "add comment" button when I clicked it followed with a description stating add an answer or reply to an answer already posted above or words to that effect so that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm copying and pasting queries from an excel spreadsheet onto the mysql command line in putty. Putty is connected the whole time. It's tricky to debug as putty puts a limit to the number of lines it displays. – garry 45 mins ago

Don't do this. Putty will drop parts of the content you paste, or place length limits on it.

Instead:

1. Export the queries from Excel into a text file on your PC, for example "exported_queries.sql".
2. Transfer that text file to your Ubuntu server, using `scp`.
3. Then open an `ssh` session to the Ubuntu server, and run the text file as input to the `mysql` program. You can do this with the `source` command in the `mysql` shell:

   ```
   mysql> source exported_queries.sql
   ```

I also recommend running `tmux` or `screen` in your Ubuntu ssh window, because those programs are good for keeping your session alive even if Putty disconnects. If you have a long-running command in your ssh session, you can reconnect and "reattach" to the session in progress.

Comment: I'm not sure what scp is, is it ok to sftp the file to my Ubuntu vps? Can I leave the line feeds and carriage returns in the sql file? I removed these in notepad+ and ran a 680 line query with begin and commit and it's still running after 45 minutes. It's parsing the code on screen at about 80 words per minute.

Comment: My putty connection is very solid , it only disconnects if I put the computer on hibernate (I think there's a setting under connections which I set to 0 to get it to stay alive)

Comment: I forgot in Putty, the scp command is called *pscp*. Documentation: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp If you're more comfortable with psftp, that's fine.

Comment: The linefeed/carriage returns will not make the query take 45 minutes. If it's a problem, it'll cause an error immediately. The 45 minutes is because your query is running, but taking a long time. I have no idea what the query is or what your database is, so I can't comment on that. If you need help optimizing an SQL query, you should probably post a new question. Include the SQL query, and the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename'` for each of the tables referenced in your query.

Comment: The reason it took so long I think was because I removed all the line breaks and carriage returns so all 680 queries were on one line. I did what you suggested except I couldn't get source to work so I tried it using sudo mysql -u root -p [database name]< [sql file path] and it added all 680 rows instantaneously almost so thanks Bill and others! Not going to be using putty for bulk queries from now on.